# How to do the same in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I want to add conditions to my queryset

How to do the same in Django (Python)?

My example code..

```
#This is example model in php...
class MY_MODEL {
    function search() {
        $params = $this->input->post('params');
        if(@$params['contact']) {
            $this->db->where('contact', $params['contact']);
        }
        return $this->db->get('my_table');
        }
}

# How to do the same in Django (Python) ?? ...
def get_queryset(self):
        my_field = self.request.GET.get('my_field', '')
        try:
            return MY_MODEL.objects.filter(
                                        if @my_field:
                                            Q(my_field__icontains=query)
                            )
        except:
            return MY_MODEL.objects.all()

        ...
```

Regards!

Comment: The good thing about django, is that it has excellent documentation: [queryset reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/), [making queries with filters guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    my_field = self.request.GET.get('my_field', '')
    my_mod_objs = MY_MODEL.objects.filter(my_field=my_field)  # assuming my field is a Model Field in your Model
    if my_mod_objs.exists():  # lazy check if there is any entry for this
        return my_mod_objs
    return MY_MODEL.objects.all()
```

Check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#filter) for more details.